# How to force Puma start in single mode on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

I m working on a Ruby app. My versions always started locally with Puma in single mode. For one week, Puma has automatically launched in cluster mode, it generates bugs, broadcasts don't launch anymore ... How can I force Puma to start in single mode ? I can't see such control on my config/puma.rb

Comment: What does your puma.rb look like?

Comment: `max_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 1 }  
min_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MIN_THREADS") { 1 }  
threads min_threads_count, max_threads_count  

port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }  

rackup      DefaultRackup  

environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }  

pidfile ENV.fetch("PIDFILE") { "tmp/pids/server.pid" }  

workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 2 }  

preload_app!  

plugin :tmp_restart`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Find this line in `config/puma.rb`. It's usually commented.

```
# workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 2 }
```

If it's uncommented then just comment it or make it like below

```
workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 0 }
```

Then puma will start in single mode.

Comment: thank you, I made your changes and now it's working :)) I clicked the useful arrow, but they say my reputation is too low to increase yours :/ wish I could help too